# How to wrap a link around a div jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below should a user to click on a button of which he is prompted for a URL. Once a URL is entered, a new `i` element is created with a link to the inputted URL wrapped around it as an `a` tag.

The code works however the link tag isn't created - how do I go about doing this?

The new link should be wrapped around that specific div only.

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".twitter_new").click(function() {
          link = prompt("Paste a url");
          if (link == null) {
          return;
          }
          else {
          div = document.createElement('i');
          $(div).addClass("fa").addClass("fa-twitter").wrapAll('<a href="' + link + '"></a>');
          $(".icons").append(div);
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wrapAll() expression doesn't modify what the variable `div` is. It returns a new object.

You are still appending the original `i` element only

I would suggest you create 2 elements or do this all as html string

```
// create `<i>`
var $i = $('<i>',{class: 'fa fa-twitter'});
// create <a> and append <i>
var $a = $('<a>', {href:link}).append($i);
// append complete <a> to dom
$(".icons").append($a);
```